# Can we control the order of directives execution

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi can we control the order of execution of directives on all page overall. Not on the same node . for eg : there are 4 directives on page on different nodes and i want to control the order of directives execution .

Comment: you mean different element of dom

Comment: yes,the use case in which if we have 10 unique directives on a page, can we control which will be evaluated first ,second overall.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't control directive execution order on different elements - they will execute as each element is parsed. And it also means you have a bad design somewhere if you're depending on your element order.

To achieve the same results, you can dynamically add and compile directives to the DOM, in the order you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can control,if your directives are different.There is priority between them.But if your directives are not different,I think You can't control.